# CAN MCP2515 - loopback mode sending messages through can-bus?

Tags: pic, spi, can-bus

I'm testing a mcu PIC in ide ccs, in loopback mode. But when I send a message, can see it in can-bus.
The datasheet says:

> The Loopback mode is a silent mode, meaning no messages will be transmitted while in this state (including error flags or Acknowledge signals). The TXCAN pin will be in a recessive state.

at read the register CANSTAT, I see in bit 7-5(OPMODE) - 010b, which means the operation mode is correct, but the loopback not silent.

where am I wrong in this?

Comment: The loopback mode should be silent with no bus activity. Have a look at the datasheet.

Comment: What does "can see it in can-bus" mean? Are you using listener software or a scope, or what? What level do you measure on the TX pin?